# Get footer to display AFTER elements with z-index

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have one div containing elements with both `relative` & `absolute` position, both with and without `z-index`.

I need another div - my footer, to display AFTER all other visible elements. It should start below the end of the lowest other element.

In my html code, the footer div DOES occur after all the others. But for some reason, it always renders under/overlapped by the others.

I can't figure out what positioning or z-index I can set to make it so the footer is never overlapped by the other elements, and always displays lowest/last on the page.

You can see the problem in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/patmeeker/9drr6qhr/

(later the length of the other elements will change dynamically. Not sure if that is a concern, but the fiddle doesn't reflect that yet)

Comment: I'm not trying to make a "sticky" footer at the bottom of the viewport, but rather just the end of the document, so not necessarily in view at all times. It would depend on the length of other elements' content.

Comment: If the height of the `absolute` positioned element is greater than the parent `div` there is no way you can reflect its height on the parent `div` as `absolute` `div`s come out of the flow of the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

it's because you're using `position: relative` with `top: 50px`, this will render the position `50px` further from the `top`, but in the flow, it's position is still in the `top` without any space, like `top: 0`, which cause your `footer` that doesn't have any `top` value to be overlapped by the content `div` with class `relNoZ`.

To overcome this, you should either give `top: 50px` to `footer` and any other sibling container (If any) or remove the `top: 50px` from the `.relNoZ`

Here's the updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyojimaru/9drr6qhr/1/)

```css
#relNoZ{
    position: relative;
    top:50px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

#absNoZ{
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left:240px;
}

#relWithZ{
    position: relative;
    left:70px;
    z-index:3;
}

#absWithZ{
    position: relative;
    left:370px;
    z-index:3;
}

#foot{
    position: relative;
    top:50px;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div id="relNoZ">
    <div id="absNoZ">
        absolute    
    </div>
    
    <div id="relWithZ">
        relative/z-index    
    </div>
    
    <div id="absWithZ">
        absolute/z-index      
    </div>
        content<br>
        content<br>
        content<br>
        content<br>
        content<br>
</div>

<div id="foot">
    footer<br>
    footer<br>
    footer<br>
    footer<br>
    footer<br>
</div>
```